# Excel VBA - Mapping different values to an entity

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

In Excel I have a table that works like the following. There are a number of people and several thousand work orders associated with those people.

This is a demo table below:

[image]

What I want in VBA is a data structure that maps each person with the amount of jobs done and total amount of money earned. So we know Jonathan did 3 jobs and earned 400 dollars.

e.x.

> (Key) -> (Value, Value)
>
> (Person) -> (Number of Jobs, Total Money)

I need the values from the Pivot Tables above but don't want to draw Pivot Tables in VBA just to get those values.

[image]

So my questions are: one - how can I write a dictionary or collection that does this in VBA and two - is a dictionary the most efficient approach. ie is there a better approach?

Comment: Use a dictionary, and the .Exists to check for dupes and compile the list from column F then use this list and worksheetfunction.sumif and .countif to do it

Comment: If a pivot table already gets you the necessary results, why do you need to do this in VBA?

Comment: @tigeravatar My end goal is not to create Pivot Tables for the results since I am doing something else with the data. I just created the Pivot Tables to show what Data I need

Comment: I would use a dictionary with values which are 2-element arrays created with `Array()`

Comment: The most efficient approach would require sorting the data.  Is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are allowed to sort the data, this will work just fine for you.  Tested on over 30,000 rows of data and it completed successfully in less than 0.1 seconds.  Commented code for clarity:

```
Sub ParseJobData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim ResultIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet          'Make sure this is the correct sheet
    Set rData = ws.Range("F1").CurrentRegion     'Make sure this is the correct range

    rData.Sort rData.Columns(1), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes    'Sort data
    aData = rData.Value                                        'Load data into array
    ReDim aResults(1 To 65000, 1 To 3)                         'Save data in Results array

    'Starting at 2 in order to skip header row
    For i = 2 To UBound(aData, 1)

        'Check if this is a new name
        'Data is sorted, so new name only happens when previous name is completed
        If aData(i, 1) <> sTemp Then
            'New name, increase ResultIndex, store the name
            ResultIndex = ResultIndex + 1
            sTemp = aData(i, 1)
            aResults(ResultIndex, 1) = sTemp
        End If

        'Column 2 is a count of jobs, increase it by 1
        aResults(ResultIndex, 2) = aResults(ResultIndex, 2) + 1

        'Column 3 is a sum of payment, increase by the amount
        aResults(ResultIndex, 3) = aResults(ResultIndex, 3) + aData(i, 3)
    Next i

    'You have now built your array of unique values with a count and sum
    'Do what you want with the array here
    'This simply outputs it
    ws.Range("J1").Resize(ResultIndex, UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou. Just a quick question when you wrote 'rData.Sort rData.Columns(1), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes' why are there no brackets/assignment? When I write 'rData = rData.Sort(rData.Columns(1), xlAscending, Header:=xlYes)' its wrong. I don't understand the syntax in play here

Comment: You only need the parentheses when you are assigning a value to an expression or method.  Unfortunately, you can't assign the sort method to a value, which is why it is on its own line, and then loaded into an array in the next line.  Because it is being sorted on its own line and there isn't any assignment or comparison going on (no `=` sign in the line), no parentheses are necessary for the Sort line.